# Google App Engine: What's My Address?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express

Standing up "Hello World" app [as published on expressjs.com](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) on Google App Engine, GAE. Here's my question, how am I supposed to access my app?

From the Google Cloud Shell, `ip addr` shows all `172.no.good.unreachable` address so I look at GAE Settings and it says something like `myappname-184271.appspot.com` hyperlinked indicating that is the URL to access my app. So, I browse to `myappname-184271.appspot.com:3000` and it times out.

Then I see Web Preview button on the GAE GUI, change my expressjs app to port 8080, and click that and my browser opens up `https://8080-dot-2959379-dot-devshell.appspot.com/` successfully showing Hello World.

How am I supposed to know that? Clearly, my app has the URL `myappname-184271.appspot.com` as indicated in the GAE Settings Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had not *deployed* my app using `gcloud app deploy`. Once you deploy the app, you'll get secure (HTTPS) address printed to your console/terminal. Pretty sweet.

BTW, launching the Web Preview from GAE actually fires up a pseudo-page that only serves up / listens on a few TCP ports. That explains that funky Web Preview URL address. It's just some machine generated URL exclusive to Web Preview.